# How to authenticate to AWS using AWS-ADFS to use Boto3 - Python

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have the following Python code to connect to a DynamoDB table in AWS:

```
# import requests
from __future__ import print_function  # Python 2/3 compatibility
import boto3
import json
import decimal
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, Attr


# Helper class to convert a DynamoDB item to JSON.
class DecimalEncoder(json.JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, o):
        if isinstance(o, decimal.Decimal):
            return str(o)
        return super(DecimalEncoder, self).default(o)


def run():
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-2')

    table = dynamodb.Table('work-gtfsr-tripupdates-dev-sydt')

    response = table.query(
        # ProjectionExpression="#yr, title, info.genres, info.actors[0]", #THIS IS A SELECT STATEMENT
        # ExpressionAttributeNames={"#yr": "year"},  # Expression Attribute Names for Projection Expression only. #SELECT STATEMENT RENAME
        KeyConditionExpression=Key('pingEpochTime').eq(1554016605) & Key('entityIndex').between(0, 500)
    )

    for i in response[u'Items']:
        print(json.dumps(i, cls=DecimalEncoder))


run()
```

The following code is confirmed to work when I connect to my personal AWS account (authenticating via AWS CLI), but it does not work behind a firewall when I am authenticating via AWS-ADFS.  When I run the code to connect to the corporate AWS instance, I get the error:

```
botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnrecognizedClientException) when calling the Query operation: The security token included in the request is invalid.
```

When I run '`aws-adfs login`' script (that is confirmed to work), it seemingly is correctly populating the .aws folder in my home drive and has worked when deploying Lambda functions in the past.  Should I be doing something in the code to accommodate aws-adfs session tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Found on another Stack Overflow page that apparently the Boto library requires the '`[default]`' entry within the ~/.aws/credentials file.

I tested the aws-adfs login script by authenticating with a profile called 'default', and everything works now.

Answer (score 0):

With boto3 you need to set up a session for your resource.

```
session =  boto3.session.Session(profile_name="other_name")
dynamodb = session.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-2')
```

Where `"other_name"` is the name of your profile you have authenticated with.

Comment: I can't comment on @dandev91 response. But when you use `aws-adfs` login, you can use it to create profiles for each account/role. If you only use the `[default]` profile, you will need to remove the credentials in that profile every time you want to run on a different account/role.
I login with `aws-adfs` with a profile and use `argparse` to accept the profile you want to use and pass that the session portion in my initial response.
  `parser.add_argument('-p', '--profile', type=str, help='aws profile')`

Then `session =  boto3.session.Session(profile_name=args.profile) `